# Using filter in clojure function

Tags: function, clojure

Why

```
(filter even? (range 10))
```

gives
    (0 2 4 6 8)

but

```
((fn [x] filter even? x)
          (range 10))
```

gives

```
(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)
```

?

Comment: Given your comment on the answer by Piotrek, it solved your problem. As such, please accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is an issue in your anonymous function - let's write it in a more readable way:

```
((fn [x]
   (do filter
       even?
       x))
 (range 10))
```

Now I think it is obvious why it returns the whole range sequence: value of `(range 10)` is bound to argument `x` and is returned as the result from your function.

The correct version would be:

```
((fn [x] (filter even? x))
 (range 10))
;; => (0 2 4 6 8)
```

Comment: Thank you very much